# How to write a loop in R to select multiple regression model and validate it?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, cross-validation, validation

I would like to run a loop in R. I have never done this before, so I would be very grateful for your help !

1. I have a sample set: 25 objects. I would like to draw 1 object from it and use it as a test set for my future external validation. The remaining 24 objects I would like to use as a training set (to select a model). I would like to repeat this process until all 25 objects are used as a test set.
2. For each of the training sets I would like to run the following code:

$\,$

```
library(leaps)
forward <- regsubsets(Y ~.,data = training, method = "forward", nbest=1)
backward <- regsubsets(Y ~.,data = training, method = "backward", nbest=1)
stepwise <- regsubsets(Y ~., data = training, method = "seqrep", nbest=1)
exhaustive <- regsubsets(Y ~.,data = training, method = "forward", nbest=1)
summary(forward)
summary(backward)
summary(stepwise) 
summary(exhaustive)
```

I would like R programme to select the best model (with the highest adjusted $R^2$) using each of the selection methods, so there are 4 final best models (e.g. the best model selected with forward selection, the best model selected with backward selection and so on...).

Afterwards I would like to perform internal cross validation of all four selected models and choose one of the four which has the lowest average mean squared error (MSE). I used to do it using the code below:

```
library(DAAG) 
val.daag<-CVlm(df=training, m=1, form.lm=formula(Y ~ X1+X2+X3)) 
val.daag<-CVlm(df=training, m=1, form.lm=formula(Y ~ X1+X2+X4)) 
val.daag<-CVlm(df=training, m=1, form.lm=formula(Y ~ X3+X4+X5)) 
val.daag<-CVlm(df=training, m=1, form.lm=formula(Y ~ X4+X5+X7))
```

For the best selected model (the lowest MSE) I would like to perform an external validation on 1 object left on the site at the beginning of the study (please refer to point 1.).

3. And loop again using different training and test set ....

I hope that you could help me with this.

If you have any suggestions how to select the best model and perform validation more efficiently, I would be happy to hear about that.

Thank you !

Comment: I'm pretty sure the leaps packagae is kind of obsolete. Have you looked into the CARET package? it's nice, and their webpage has some nice examples and eveh theory: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/featureselection.html